# Not able to see "Inspect Element" option on Edge browser for Some website

Tags: microsoft-edge, devtools, inspect-element

Open Edge browser and right click - Some web application able to Inspect Element option. But some of the web application not able to see Inpect Element option.
How to Solve this issue? I need inspect element option. Also getting message DevTool was disconnected from the page.

[image: DevTool was disconnected from the page]

Comment: Does this happened only with edge ? Did you noticed it on multiple websites ?

Comment: Yes, This is happed with edge only

Comment: what is the version of the Microsoft Edge? If you can share the website url  so that we can reproduce this issue, I think this will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it was caused by the fact that the site was loaded with IE mode.

What helped me was a workaround but DevTools was working for that pages.

1. In Windows, open the Run dialog. For example, press the Windows logo key + R or right click on the Start menu and select "Run"
2. Put there the following command while you have opened Edge with the desired site.

   %systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe
3. It will open new windows where you can select which page you want to open with Developers tools and it works also for IE mode pages.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/